# How to get the variables of id from another queried looped map's id

Tags: javascript, next.js, graphql

So I'm trying to get the userId from another queried looped map's id.

The error is:
Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.

The error started showing when I added this inside the map:

```
const { data: { getUser } = {} } = useQuery(FETCH_USER_QUERY, {
          variables: {
            userId: something?.id,
          },
        });
```

on my component... This is my full component code:

```
export default function SomethingComponent() {
  const { data: { getSomething } = {} } = useQuery(
    FETCH_SOMETHING_QUERY
  );

  return (
    <>
      {getSomething?.map((something) => {
        const { data: { getUser } = {} } = useQuery(FETCH_USER_QUERY, {
          variables: {
            userId: something?.id,
          },
        });
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>{getUser.name}</h1>
            {/* ... */}
            {/* ... */}
            {/* ... */}
            {/* ... */}
            {/* ... */}
            {/* ... */}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

And this is for the Query of Something:

```
const FETCH_SOMETHING_QUERY = gql`
  {
    getSomething {
      id
    }
  }
`;
```

And for the query of the user:

```
const FETCH_USER_QUERY = gql`
  query ($userId: ID!) {
    getUser(userId: $userId) {
        # ...
    }
  }
`;
```

Ive tried thinking on how to fix this myself but i dont know any other way to get the something.id without going inside the looped map. So i tried searching for the same error and they are about the hooks in the wrong order or place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did was breaking the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

You'll need to utilize [useApolloClient](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#useapolloclient) hook in order to manually execute the queries.

However, since we need to get the users individually, we can approach two ways for this.

The first way is to get the initial data first, then put it in `useEffect` hook with `client` extracted from `useLazyQuery` and then set the state one by one (which I think is a bit complicated):

The code below is just an idea. I won't guarantee that it will work if you copy+paste it.

```js
// your previous code here
const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
const {
  client
} = useApolloClient()

useEffect(() => {
  if (getSomething.length > 0) {
    getSomething.forEach(async({
      id: userId
    }) => {
      const {
        data: newUsers
      } = await client.query({
        query: FETCH_USER_QUERY,
        variables: {
          userId,
        },
      })
      setUsers([...users, ...newUsers])
    })
  }
}, [getSomething])
```

2nd approach is to breakdown the component into smaller one with a fetch logic inside it.

```js
export default function SomethingComponent() {
  const { data: { getSomething } = {} } = useQuery(
    FETCH_SOMETHING_QUERY
  );

  return (
    <>
    {getSometing.map((user) => <UserComponent userId={user.id} />)}
    </>
  );
}

// UserComponent.js
export default function UserComponent({ userId }) {
  const { data: { user } = {} } = useQuery(
    FETCH_USER_QUERY, { variables: { userId } }
  );

  return (
    <>
    {user?.name}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: i chose the 2nd option as i believed it has more guarantee of it working and it did. I saw your first approach and I think I would use it a bit later. thanks. Though I did change variables: { userId }  to variables: { userId: userId }

Comment: If you're using your ES6, you don't need `userId: userId`. Just `userId` is fine as it was destructured from prop params from `UserComponent`.

Comment: no its because i need userId like this userId: "id"  and the prop will only be for the "id"